# Data type for std::string or std::endl

Tags: c++, string, types, c++17, endl

I have the following function template:

```cpp
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <typename Streamable>
void printall(std::vector<Streamable>& items, std::string sep = "\n")
{
    for (Streamable item : items)
        std::cout << item << sep;
}

#endif
```

Now I'd like to set the default value of `sep`to `std::endl` instead, which is a function, not a `std::string`.
But I'd also like the user to be able to pass in a `std::string`.
How must I specify the argument `sep`'s type to accept both, an arbitrary `std::string` as well as `std::endl`?

Comment: You should use the same type as used in the [`std::endl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) declaration. But what actually bothers you with the implementation you have?!?

Comment: `std::endl` is a function, that outputs `\n` and then calls `flush()` on the stream. Why do you want to flush after each item? If you want to flush at all, it makes sense to do that once, after the loop.

Comment: Fair points. Maybe this does not make too much sense in this scenario. I'd still like to know whether it is possible.

Comment: If you insist: `template <typename Streamable, typename Sep = decltype(std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char>>)> void printall(std::vector<Streamable>& items, Sep sep = std::endl)` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zc451sMcP). This accepts as a separator anything that could be written to `std::cout` (not just strings and `std::endl`)

Comment: Thank you. I read this, as it only works by extending the template. Now I am convinced, that I do not want to do that.

Comment: You could also write two overloads, one that takes a single parameter and uses `std::endl`, and one that takes two parameters, the second being `std::string` without default argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the default value for the second parameter to be `std::endl`, then you can simply add an overload that takes only one parameter, and don't provide a default for the `string` overload. This will give you the overload set that you desire.

```
template <typename Streamable>
void printall(std::vector<Streamable>const & items)  // gets called when second 
                                                     // argument is not passed in
{
    for (Streamable const & item : items)
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
}

template <typename Streamable>
void printall(std::vector<Streamable> const & items, std::string const & sep)
{
    for (Streamable const & item : items)
        std::cout << item << sep;
}
```